# Using the flip-and-drag method to draw a convolution

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals

So, we are asked to graphically convolve (using the flip-and-drag method) the following pair of signals: $$x_1(t) = \delta(t+1)-2\delta(t-1) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_2(t) =  \begin{cases} -1-2t, & -\frac{1}{2}\leq t\leq 0 \\ -1+2t, & 0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & |t|>\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

where $\delta(t)$ is the dirac delta function.

I don't know how to draw using Latex, so I am going to try and describe you what I've drawn so far using words (as best as I can). So, I've successfully been able to draw $x_2(t)$ (which gives me an inverted triangle whose summits coordinates are : $\left(-\frac{1}{2}, 0\right), \left(\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right)$ and $\left(0, -1 \right)$).

My problem starts when I have to draw $x_1(t)$. After doing some research, I have found that we represent the dirac delta function using "arrows", but I still don't know how to draw $x_1(t)$ .

Also, if we assume I was able to draw it (i.e I would have a graph with arrows), how am I supposed to draw the convolution (using the flip and drag method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolution is a linear operator, so let me explain just how to convolve $x_2(t)$ with $\delta(t-t_0)$. The only thing you would have to do afterwards is to convolve the same signal $x_2(t)$ with the other Dirac delta, multiply the function you get by some amplitude, and then add both convolution results.

The Dirac delta has what is known as sifting property:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\delta(t-t_0)\,\mathrm{d}t=f(t_0)$$

This means that if we multiply a function by an impulse located at $t=t_0$, the area under that differential along the $t$-axis corresponds to the value of the function at $t_0$.

To solve your convolution graphically, imagine the following. Leave the impulses where they are. Then flip your convoluting signal, $x_2(t)$, and take it to start at $-\infty$. Start sliding this function to the right. At first, the convolution (the integral) returns $0$ for all $t$ because the product of $x_2(t)$ and $\delta(t+1)$ is $0$, as they are not intersecting anywhere. But, at some point, they both come across each other. This will continue to happen as long as the sliding version of $x_2(t)$ takes some non-zero value in $t=t_0$. When the triangle goes through entirely, then the convolution will be zero for every other $t$ again, as they will not encounter again.

I'll put some (extremely rudimentary) drawings to make this easier to see.

[image]

The first picture corresponds to the cases where the triangle and the impulse don't take any non-zero values at common points. The second one, where the triangle and the impulse are both non-zero at some value (in this case, always at $t_0$). The third picture corresponds to the moment where the triangle has passed through entirely, and thus the convolution is $0$ again.

Try to think about it, and do it on your own. As a rule of thumb, convoluting with deltas is by far the easiest convolution that there can be. In general, if we have something like this (with $A$ being some constant that represents the amplitude of the impulse): $$g(t)=f(t)*A\delta(t-t_0)$$ Then $g(t)$ will just be $f(t)$ but centered at $t_0$ and multiplied by $A$. That means, you just shift $f(t)$ and invert it or scale it depending on the value of $A$.

Comment: Just a question though. My teacher has defined the dirac delta function using the following property: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t_{0}) \delta (t-t_{0}) dt_{0} = x(t)$. Does your definition of the property of the dirac delta function say the same thing ? Because, if it does, I have trouble seeing it. Yours seems actually more clear to me

Comment: @Skyris That's pretty weird actually, as one uses subscripts to denote constant values. Nevertheless, what is inside the integral is the same. He just called $t$ what I called $t_0$ and $t_0$ what I called $t$. They are the same because  $$\delta(x)=\delta(-x)$$ Apart from that, be careful with the integration limits. If the impulse is outside $(a,b)$, then the integral will be $0$ for all values of $t$. If it is inside that interval, then everything is right. That's why convolution is defined in $(-\infty,\infty)$, to avoid skipping any values.